# Rails erb templating, link element visibility to action in yield?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

In application.html.erb file, can I link HTML elements visibility to actions that are inside the <%= yield %> tag ?

For example if I have a header element and want to display a text there if <%= yield %> is displaying a specific action?

Comment: You need to give a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [current_page?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) helper to determine if you're on a specific page (as identified with the given path parameters, etc.) and branch accordingly.

Or, if you need a more broad stroke you can use [controller_name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-c-controller_name) and/or `action_name` to get the current controller's name and the current action's name and branch accordingly.

Lastly, you can inspect `params[:controller]` or `params[:action]`, which are sometimes more revealing than the above.